# Does a Rogue's Evasion work for spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature, rogue, saving-throw

The Rogue class at level 2 gain the ability [Evasion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Rogue/#Evasion_Ex):

> At 2nd level and higher, a rogue can avoid even magical and unusual
>   attacks with great agility. If she makes a successful Reflex saving
>   throw against an attack that normally deals half damage on a
>   successful save, she instead takes no damage. Evasion can be used only
>   if the rogue is wearing light armor or no armor. A helpless rogue does
>   not gain the benefit of evasion.

Does this also apply to spells that have a Reflex save for half damage, such as [Fireball](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, rogues can evade AoE spells and other such effects

The term "attack" here isn't actually being used in any kind of special sense, and the ability should probably have been written to refer to "effects" instead of "attacks". Nonetheless, the intention is that if the rogue would be subject to any damaging effect which allows targets to make a reflex save for half damage, Evasion will apply.